# How can i put pie chart from Chart.js inside the table?

Tags: javascript, html, charts

I am creating a page in which i want to put result in pie chart.i am able to create pie chart but not able to put the pie chart front of every section.right now it is coming very below and also the size of the chart is very big .I want small one and in front of every section.Below is the code

HTML:-

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <script src="myscript.js"></script> 

<section class="container py-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2>Survey</h2>
            <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#personalInfo" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase active">Personal Info</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#section1" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase">Section 1</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#section2" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase">Section 2</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="" data-target="#results" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link small text-uppercase">Results</a></li>
            </ul>
            <br>
            <div id="tabsContent" class="tab-content">
                <div id="personalInfo" class="tab-pane fade active show">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="fullName">Full Name address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="fullName" aria-describedby="nameHelp" placeholder="Enter full name">
                        <small id="nameHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Please enter your full name.</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                        <small id="email" class="form-text text-muted">Please enter your valid email address.</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="age">Password</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="age" aria-describedby="age" placeholder="Age">
                        <small id="age" class="form-text text-muted">Please enter your age in number.</small>
                    </div>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext" >Next</a>

                </div>
                <div id="section1" class="section_main tab-pane fade">
                    <div class="section-1-questions">
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 1:</legend>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios1" value="1" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios2" value="2" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="gridRadios3" value="3" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios3">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 2:</legend>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios4" value="1" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios4">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios5" value="2" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios5">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question2" id="gridRadios6" value="3" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios6">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 3:</legend>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios7" value="1" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios7">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios8" value="2" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios8">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question3" id="gridRadios9" value="3" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios9">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-nav-group">
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="section2" class="section_main tab-pane fade">
                    <div class="section-2-question">
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios10" value="1" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios10">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios11" value="2" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios11">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question4" id="gridRadios12" value="3" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios12">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 5:</legend>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios13" value="1" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios13">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios14" value="2" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios14">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question5" id="gridRadios15" value="3" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios15">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios16" value="1" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios16">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios17" value="2" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios17">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question6" id="gridRadios18" value="3" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios18">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Question 4:</legend>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios19" value="1" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios19">
                                            1
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios20" value="2" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios20">
                                            2
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check section-2">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question7" id="gridRadios21" value="3" />
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios21">
                                            3
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-nav-group">
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <!-- <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext" >Next</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious" >Previous</a> -->
                </div>
                <div id="results" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <div class="final-results"></div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="final-results"></div>
              <div class="canvas-holder">
                <canvas id="resultsChart1" ></canvas></div>
                <div class="canvas-holder"><canvas id="resultsChart2"></canvas></div>
                    <br>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="displayRadioValue()">
                        Show Results
                    </button>
                    <br>
                    <div class="spider-chart" id="container2" style="min-width: 400px; max-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
                    <br>
                    <div id="control" style="display: none">
                        <a id="toemail" class="btn btn-link" href="mailto:youremail@domain.com?subject=Survey response&body=">Send to
                            email</a>&nbsp;<button onclick="window.print();" class="btn btn-warning">Send to PDF</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</section>
```

JS :-

```
function displayRadioValue() {
    let section1 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-1 > input[type="radio"]')
    let section2 = document.querySelectorAll('.section-2 > input[type="radio"]')
    let sectionnew = document.querySelectorAll('#section1').values
    let fullName = document.querySelector('#fullName').value
    let email = document.querySelector('#email').value
    let age = document.querySelector('#age').value
    var ctx1 = document.querySelector('#resultsChart1').getContext('2d');
    var ctx2 = document.querySelector('#resultsChart2').getContext('2d');
    let section1Total = 0
    let section2Total = 0
    let section1Question = 0
    let section2Question = 0
    let finalResults = document.querySelector('.final-results')
    let result1 = ''
    let result2 = ''
    finalResults.innerHTML = ''
  
    //Section 1
    section1.forEach(function(radio, index) {
        if (radio.checked) {
            section2Question++
            section1Total += +radio.value
        }
    })
    console.log('radio value:',$("input[name='question1']:checked").val());
   // console.log( $("input[name=‘question1’]:checked").val());
   console.log("Ruchir");
    //Section 2
    section2.forEach(function(radio, index) {
        if (radio.checked) {
            section1Question++
            section2Total += +radio.value
        }
    })
  
    var options1 = {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: ["Section 1 Result%", "Remaining%"],
            datasets: [{
                backgroundColor: [
                    "#2ecc71",
                    "#3498db",],
                
                data: [((section1Total / (section1Question * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2), (100 - ((section1Total / (section1Question * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2))],
                
            },
                
            ]
        },
        
    }
    var options2 = {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: ["Section 2 Result%", "Remaining%"],
            datasets: [{
                backgroundColor: [
                    "#2ecc71",
                    "#3498db",],
                
                data: [((section2Total / (section2Question * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2), (100 - ((section2Total / (section2Question * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2))],
                
            },
                
            ]
        },
        
    }
  
    //Final Results and validation
    if (fullName.value != '' && email.value != '' && age.value != '') {
        if (section1Total > 0 && section2Total > 0) {
            finalResults.innerHTML += genDetails(fullName, email, age)
            finalResults.innerHTML += "<h2>Results</h2>"
            finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section1Question, section1Total, 1)
            new Chart(ctx1, options1); //show chart
            new Chart(ctx2, options2); //show chart
            finalResults.innerHTML += genTable(section2Question, section2Total, 2)
            finalResults.innerHTML += $("input[name='question1']:checked").val()
            finalResults.innerHTML += "<h2>Chart Results</h2>"
            document.getElementById("control").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("resultsChart").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("toemail").href += document.querySelector(".final-results").innerText;
            //new Chart(ctx, options); //show chart
        } else {
            finalResults.innerHTML = 'Snap! Please select the atleast one survey question from each section '
        }
    } else {
        finalResults.innerHTML = 'Snap! Please enter your name, emial, age in the first section '
    }
  }
  
  function genDetails(name, email, age) {
    var result = "<h2>Personal Info</h2>"
    result += "<b>Full name:</b> <span>" + name + "</span><br>"
    result += "<b>Email name:</b> <span>" + email + "</span><br>"
    result += "<b>Age: </b> <span>" + age + "</span><br>"
    return result
  }
  
  function genTable(ques, total, section) {
    var result = "<b>Section " + section + ":</b><br>"
    var tr = "<tr><th>" + total + "</th><th>" + ((total / (ques * 3)) * 100).toFixed(2) + "</th></tr>"
    result += "<table><thead><tr><th>Total Score</th><th>Percentage</th></tr></thead><tbody>" + tr + "</tbody></table>"
    return result
  }

  $('input[type="radio"]').on("change", function () {
    let all_radio = $(this).closest(".section_main").find('input[type="radio"]');
    let checked_radio = $(this).closest(".section_main").find('input[type="radio"]:checked');

    if (checked_radio.length == all_radio.length / 3) {
        $(this).closest(".section_main").find(".btn-nav-group").append('<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>');
    }
});

$(".btnNext").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("ul.nav-tabs li.nav-item a.active").closest("li").next("li").find("a").trigger("click");
});

//   $(document).ready(function(){
// //   $('.btnNext').click(function(){
// //     $('.nav-tabs .active').closest('li').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
// //   });
  
//   $('.btnPrevious').click(function(){
//     $('.nav-tabs .active').closest('li').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
//   });
// });
```

CSS:-

```
canvas {
    display: none
}
.canvas-holder {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }

@media print {
    body * {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    canvas {
        visibility: visible;
        margin-top: 30%;
    }
    .form-control {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    .final-results * {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    .spider-chart * {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    .final-results,
    .form-control {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
}

table,
table tr th,
table tr td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Conver the chart into image and put it anywhere you want. `chart.toBase64Image()` will give you data image url. You can then put it into an img tag and give it some height width as per your needs

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan thanks but i never use it can you give me example